# Duplicate fields in my (kendo grid) exported data file

Tags: kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and export button in my application.Exporting grid data is working fine but here some rows are repeated  and they are displaying at the end of the file.And here i gave custom name for the exported file.Can any one tell me whats wrong in my code. please?
here is the export button click code

```
      $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
  var dataSource=  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource; 
  var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource( { 
  data: dataSource.data(), 
  filter: dataSource.filter() 
 }); 
 filteredDataSource.read();
 var data = filteredDataSource.view();

    var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";

 result += "<table><tr><th>OrderID</th><th>Freight</th><th>Order Date</th><th>Ship Name</th><th>Ship City</th></tr>";

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     result += "<tr>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].OrderID;
     result += "</td>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].Freight;
     result += "</td>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += kendo.format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", data[i].OrderDate);
     result += "</td>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].ShipName;
     result += "</td>";

     result += "<td>";
     result += data[i].ShipCity;
     result += "</td>";

     result += "</tr>";
 }

 result += "</table>";
 var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var mins = dt.getMinutes();
    var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + " " + hour + ":" + mins;
    var a = document.createElement('a');
  var table_div = (document.getElementById('grid').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]);
var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace( );
 a.href = result + ',' + table_html;
      a.download = 'exporteddata@'  +postfix+ '.xls';
    a.click();
 e.preventDefault();
                                                    });
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/35/

Comment: I have tried you code on fiddle but it didn't export any file for me.Then i tried on my local system and it worked after addign  $(a).appendTo('body'); in end.But excel file that i received didn't have any repeated rows.But it conatain some unreadable line.Is it your problem ?

Comment: ya exactly that is my problem

Comment: a.href = result + ',' + table_html; But this was solved when i removed table_html from the a.href.Try this:" **a.href = result;** " instead of **a.href = result + ',' + table_html;**

Comment: I tried that one ,here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/38/,but last row is missing,I have 830 rows,but it displaying 829 rows.

Comment: It worked fine on my local machine.One issue that i found in your fiddle code is that  **for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {}**
But on local you have done correct **for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {}**.Please verify once .Check here http://jsfiddle.net/SZBrt/40/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modify this to on fiddle code:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) 
   {
       //your code
   }
```

to

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
   {
       //your code
   }
```